# Returning a number with varying # of digits between fixed characters

Tags: database, url, terminal

Im writing my bachelor thesis on behavioral economics, and in this coherence I have aquired a dataset with 40.000 different observations/rows.

The data is from a forum, and some of the rows are the start of the topic, and the others are the replies. However, i need to group matching rows. I have tried by using the text functions in excel, removing the "RE:" from the replies, giving the topic and replies a variable with an identical value(which is the goal!)..

But because my data has some missing values in the "topic" variable(see attached image), i have to use another variable for identification... Which leads to my question:

Is it possible to run a terminal command(mac user), that can take a list of URLS, and separate digits between characters and output it in a text file of some kind?

My urls looks like this:

```
http://www.lydmaskinen.dk/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=63898&p=553224#p553224
```

Where it is the number from "&t=" to "&p", and in some cases nothing at the endI am interested in.

[A little more describing screendump](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3592722/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202015-01-29%20kl.%2000.29.21.png)

Thanks,

Comment: Ps. Hope i posted this correctly... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for your URLs:

```
echo 'http://www.lydmaskinen.dk/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=63898&p=553224#p553224' | cut -f2 -d '&' | cut -f2 -d '='
```

To do it on the whole column of URLs I need to know what the filetype is (CSV, TSV, xls?)